# Find/Remove suspected virus/malware on macbook air (mapi.sport80.com)

Tags: malware, virus, macos, virus-removal

I've found a program running on a friend's Mac that is under the name "mapi.sport80.com" in screen time & it has been running consistently for 5 days straight, it looks to be accessing system preferences (has roughly 14 hours a day on screen time).

Is there any way to find the program that is running? I can't find it by searching the name of the program. I'm guessing it has covered it up somehow.
A scan has also been run using Norton antivirus but nothing was found.

Answer (score 0):

They must likely are running one of sport80.com’s integrations, which calls their API. See https://www.sport80.com/integrations